# How to close modal in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to close modal from home component.my close button is in home component.If i click close button i want to close modal.If i click close button from home component how to set visible value is false from home component. How can i use service for that? or any other way is there? How do it?

dialog.component.html

```
    <div [@dialog] *ngIf="visible" class="dialog">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <button *ngIf="closable" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close" class="dialog__close-btn">X</button>
      <app-home></app-home>
      </div>
    <div *ngIf="visible" class="overlay" (click)="close()"></div>
```

home.component.ts:

```
    <button (click)="showDialog = !showDialog" class="btn">Close</button>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7zdnwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this approach from [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) and it works ok.

You Parent is **Dialog** and child is **app-home**. So emitter is defined in child class like this

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() close = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ...

  // <button (click)="onClose()" in html
  onClose() {
    this.close.emit(true)
  }

}
```

and listen for the event in parent **dialog** class like this

```
// html
<app-home (close)="onCloseClick($event)"></app-home>

// Class code
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  onCloseClick(close: Boolean) {
    if(close){
      this.close()
    }
  }

   ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe i can. Or not. It someone else will. Sure please ask.